# How can you change the permalink for pages?

Tags: categories, pages, permalinks

When I set my permalink to '/%category%/%postname%.html' this will work for all the posts, but the pages still don't have a .html at the end. Is there a way I can fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a very basic plugin that does just that: [.html on Pages](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/html-on-pages/)